# browser.download.dir does not work on Selenium with Python within Docker

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I am trying to custom the folder where to download files through Selenium + Python, but it does not change anything.

Here is my code:

```
opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
profile = FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)  # Use a custom folder for downloads
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", '/app')  # Set the custom download folder path
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream")  # Disable the download dialog
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path='./geckodriver', options=opts)
```

I tried as well: `profile.update_preferences()` but it does not work

I execute the code with docker-compose, but after checking the inner folders, never got any new file once i did click on a button to download the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to one of these ways:

- You need to pass and absolute path string, a relative one won't work
  on firefox.
- You can use pathlib to pass the absolute path string of a relative path.

---

### Example using fullPath

```
# WORKING AS IT MUST BE AN ABSOLUTE PATH
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", r'[your_full_path_here]') # use the fullpath
```

### Example using pathlib relativePath

```
# ALSO WORKING
from pathlib import Path

myPath = Path('./app').absolute()
pathToFolder=myPath._str
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", pathToFolder) # use the fullpath
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesnt work on Docker, in local works perfectly

Comment: At the end I just solve it setting the download.dir to another folder on a volume connected with the host, and it works there! thank you anyway!